# com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning entitlement missing error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am implementing apple pay in my application, when I am doing this, receiving an error

> com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning entitlement missing error

when researching this, I have found that apple should manually add the profile to our account, so I requested apple regarding this and they also added the profile to my account but I am still facing an issue. Can someone please provide me any sample to sort this out?

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer for this. First we need the whitelisting our account from Apple. we need to send the mail to **apple-pay-provisioning@apple.com** and **apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com** for whitelisting. After some enquiry apple approved our account as whitelisted.

After our account is whitelisted we are able to see the Additional Capabilities in our [Apple developer appId edit screen](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/bundleId)

[image]

We need to enable the checkbox `In-App Provisioning`. After that we are able to add the `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` in our entitlement. In Xcode 13 we are using the provisioning in Automatic manage signing option(No need to manual profile and certificate).